# Puppeteer innerHTML page evaluate functions returning null and undefined errors

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

await page.$eval('.class1' + variable + ' img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');

I also tried

await page.evaluate((variable) '.class1' + variable + ' img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');

I know that all my if statements enclosing this function are correct, and in inspector, the .class1VARIABLE img.class2 selection's .ParentElement returns the appropriate element.

Yet, when I run first function I get error around finding ParentElement of undefined, and when I run second function I get error around finding ParentElement of null. What gives? Am I failing to pass the variable in correctly? Am I evaluating the wrong DOM? 'variable' is doing the right thing, incrementing in a for statement, and I've verified that it's correct with console.log debugging statements within the logic that gets me here. I even tried hardcoding the variable inside the function, like

await page.evaluate(() '.class1VARIABLE img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');

which I can't even comprehend how it would fail, and it crashed with either the null or undefined error also.

Kinda at the end of my wits here.

P.S. Ifit matters, the image's ParentElement is a td.

Comment: It seems there are some errors in your examples: `await page.evaluate((variable) '.class1' + variable + ' img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');` and `await page.evaluate(() '.class1VARIABLE img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');` are syntactically wrong.

Comment: ...ok... you gonna specify HOW?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot surely suppose, These fragments should throw syntax errors. At least something like this should be tried: `await page.evaluate((selector) => { document.querySelector(selector).ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute'; }, '.class1' + variable + ' img.class2');` 
or 
`await page.evaluate((selector) => { document.querySelector(selector).ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute'; }, '.class1VARIABLE img.class2');`

Comment: They don't throw syntax errors. I'll try your suggestions. The selector is '.class1VARIABLE img.class2', for example.

Comment: Maybe you quote them with some omissions or inaccurate editions? For me, they throw `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` or `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`.

Comment: Here's another form I try, same result: await page.$eval('.class1' + variable + ' img.class2', el => el.ParentElement.innerHTML = 'text to substitute');

Comment: Unfortunately, without a minimal working code example with reproducible error, it is hard to say what can be wrong. Try to reduce your script to such a test code, maybe it would be easier for somebody to help you.

Comment: Can you use puppeteer to change the innerHTML of an element with a .class selector? That's all I'm trying to do. I can change the class to mine, and the string to substitute.

Comment: Yes, you can. I will add an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of how to  change the innerHTML of an element with a .class selector:

```js
'use strict';

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body><p class='test'>Text.</p></body>
  </html>`;

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const pSelector = '.test';
    const newHTML = '<i>New text.</i>';

    await page.evaluate((selector, html) => {
      document.querySelector(selector).parentElement.innerHTML = html;
    }, pSelector, newHTML);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is 'selector' doing in the function? Is it not declared? Some sort of placeholder? What is pSelector doing?

Comment: `pSelector` is a variable that is defined in the Node.js scope (main script scope). Function argument of `page.evaluate()` is executed in the document (browser) scope and has no access to the main script scope (including `pSelector` variable). To transfer any variables of main script scope to document (browser) scope, we need to add them as second, third, etc. arguments in the `page.evaluate()` function and they will become parameters of the evaluated function (in this example — `selector` parameter). So `querySelector` and `selector` have the same value but are accessed from different scopes.

Comment: You can just hardcode the selector value in the evaluated function if this suffices. But if I understand correctly, You need to call the same function in a loop with incremented counter, so you need to use this scope interaction: define the incrementing variable in the Node.js scope and transfer it to the function evaluated in the document scope.

Comment: Ran that code, getting "Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" again. Maybe it's to do with the .ParentElement part. Where would you insert the parent-ness? pass in pSelector.ParentElement? define pSelector = '.test.ParentElement'? Remember, I have to get an img by class, and then change its parent, (a td), with .innerHTML.

Comment: aside, is there any reason for try{ ing the whole main function? Puppeteer already essentially does that. I try{ed the page.evaluate function in my code.

Comment: You suggest an edition with setting innerHTML for an image. I do not think this is valid, as images cannot have children, so innerHTML for them does not seem right.

Comment: Sure, you can wrap in `try` any fragment, I've just got accustomed to wrap the whole main function.

Comment: As a risky suggestion: try `document.querySelector(selector).parentElement .innerHTML = ...`.

Comment: Oh, maybe it is just a typo? it is [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), not `ParentElement`.

Comment: running essentially the code above, getting it to change the innerHTML of the <td>, but it's also throwing errors at the line await page.evaluate((selector..... like crazy, saying cannot get parentElement of null. So, it's working some of the time, and evaluating the element as null some of the time...

Comment: Well, as I've said, without a minimal working code example with reproducible error, it is hard to say what can be wrong.

Comment: Just figured out why it's erring. It succeeds, which draws the new text, but that replaces the img with the class1 attribute. I think once I add an empty img with class1 to the end of my innerHTML, I'll be golden!

Comment: Last question: how to pass in new HTML content (text) as a variable?

Comment: Just add another variable/argument pair. I've edited the example to show a possible variant.